# autoit not able to read text on web browser

Tags: window, controls, autoit

When I open a browser in IE and Chrome and try to identify controls, I can only see the window='Chrome_widgetwin_1' and control='intermediate D3D window' in chrome. In IE I can only see window='IEFrame' and control='internet explorer_server'. Hovering over anything else including links and buttons still only shows these (even as mouse coordinates change). I also can't seem to view any significant text on the pages hidden or visible. I'm trying to get the coordinates of different controls and text strings but can't.

I tried the following to see controls on the page as well when I had the browser open as active page:

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
ConsoleWrite("Make your window active!" & @CRLF)
Sleep(5000)
GetAllWindowsControls(WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]"))
Func GetAllWindowsControls($hCallersWindow, $bOnlyVisible=Default, $sStringIncludes=Default, $sClass=Default)
; Get all list of controls
If $bOnlyVisible = Default Then $bOnlyVisible = False
If $sStringIncludes = Default Then $sStringIncludes = ""
If $sClass = Default Then $sClass = ""
$sClassList = WinGetClassList($hCallersWindow)
; Create array
$aClassList = StringSplit($sClassList, @CRLF, 2)
; Sort array
_ArraySort($aClassList)
_ArrayDelete($aClassList, 0)
; Loop
$iCurrentClass = ""
$iCurrentCount = 1
$iTotalCounter = 1
If StringLen($sClass)>0 Then
For $i = UBound($aClassList)-1 To 0 Step - 1
If $aClassList[$i]<>$sClass Then
_ArrayDelete($aClassList,$i)
EndIf
Next
EndIf
For $i = 0 To UBound($aClassList) - 1
If $aClassList[$i] = $iCurrentClass Then
$iCurrentCount += 1
Else
$iCurrentClass = $aClassList[$i]
$iCurrentCount = 1
EndIf
$hControl = ControlGetHandle($hCallersWindow, "", "[CLASSNN:" & $iCurrentClass & $iCurrentCount & "]")
$text = StringRegExpReplace(ControlGetText($hCallersWindow, "", $hControl), "[\n\r]", "{@CRLF}")
$aPos = ControlGetPos($hCallersWindow, "", $hControl)
$sControlID = _WinAPI_GetDlgCtrlID($hControl)
$bIsVisible = ControlCommand($hCallersWindow, "", $hControl, "IsVisible")
If $bOnlyVisible And Not $bIsVisible Then
$iTotalCounter += 1
ContinueLoop
EndIf
If StringLen($sStringIncludes) > 0 Then
If Not StringInStr($text, $sStringIncludes) Then
$iTotalCounter += 1
ContinueLoop
EndIf
EndIf
If IsArray($aPos) Then
MsgBox(0,"","Func=[GetAllWindowsControls]: ControlCounter=[" & StringFormat("%3s", $iTotalCounter) & "] ControlID=[" & StringFormat("%5s", $sControlID) & "] Handle=[" & StringFormat("%10s", $hControl) & "] ClassNN=[" & StringFormat("%19s", $iCurrentClass & $iCurrentCount) & "] XPos=[" & StringFormat("%4s", $aPos[0]) & "] YPos=[" & StringFormat("%4s", $aPos[1]) & "] Width=[" & StringFormat("%4s", $aPos[2]) & "] Height=[" & StringFormat("%4s", $aPos[3]) & "] IsVisible=[" & $bIsVisible & "] Text=[" & $text & "]." & @CRLF)
Else
MsgBox(0,"","Func=[GetAllWindowsControls]: ControlCounter=[" & StringFormat("%3s", $iTotalCounter) & "] ControlID=[" & StringFormat("%5s", $sControlID) & "] Handle=[" & StringFormat("%10s", $hControl) & "] ClassNN=[" & StringFormat("%19s", $iCurrentClass & $iCurrentCount) & "] XPos=[winclosed] YPos=[winclosed] Width=[winclosed] Height=[winclosed] Text=[" & $text & "]." & @CRLF)
EndIf
If Not WinExists($hCallersWindow) Then ExitLoop
$iTotalCounter += 1
Next
EndFunc   ;==>GetAllWindowsControls
```

When I run it I get this output indicating that its not seeing any controls in the browser:[image]